# How is $O(\log n)$ a subset of $O(n^b)$?

Tags: asymptotics, education

This is an excerpt from a textbook I am reading:

> A number of useful shortcuts can be applied when using asymptotic
>   notation. First:
>
> $O(n^{c_1}) \subset O(n^{c_2})$
>
> for any $c_1 < c_2.$ Second: For any constants $a,b,c>0,$
>
> $O(a) \subset O(\log n) \subset O(n^b) \subset O(c^n)$
>
> These inclusion relations can be multiplied by any positive value, and
>   they still hold. For example, multiplying by n yields:
>
> $O(n) \subset O(n \log  n) \subset O(n^{1+b}) \subset O(nC^n)$

I'm wondering how $O(\log n)$ is a subset of $O(n^b)$

Also how are functions subsets of other functions?

Comment: Functions are not subsets of other functions - but $O(f(n))$ denotes a _set_, not a function: the set of all functions whose asymptotic growth is bounded by a multiple of $f(n)$.

Comment: Try calculating the limit of their ratio to see whether you can bound that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f \in O(\log{n})$. Then there is a constant $C > 0$ for which $f(n) \le C \log{n}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

On the other hand, for every $\alpha > 0$ we have $\log{n} < n^\alpha$ for large enough $n$; this can be seen readily enough by looking at the graphs of $\log{n}$ and $n^{\alpha}$, or by observing that the function $e^x$ grows faster than $x^n$ for every $n$.

Hence, for large $n$, we've got $f(n) \le C \log{n} < C n^{\alpha}$ so that $f \in O(n^{\alpha})$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

$$u\in O(v)\implies O(u)\subseteq O(v)$$

Comment: You made a logical answer, but I don't understand how this applies with functions/graphs.

Comment: What is [your definition of O(f)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by showing $\frac{a}{\log n} \rightarrow L_1$, $\frac{\log n}{n^b} \rightarrow L_2$ and $\frac{n^b}{c^n} \rightarrow L_3$ where $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are finite. (in fact they are zero).

This may be not true for any $c>0$. If we take $c=0.1,b=5$, then, is it possible to prove $O(n^b) \subset O(c^n)$? For $c>1$, it is true.